# How to evaluate the following Gaussian integral by completing the summation of squares

Tags: integration, bayesian, gaussian, laplace-method

I read this paper on parameter estimation using Bayesian theory, and I came across the following integral that I did not know how to solve.
We have the following joint posterior probability for the parameters $A$ and $\alpha$,

$P(A\alpha|D\rho I)=exp(-\frac{Q}{2\rho^2})$

where

$Q=\sum_{i=1}^{N}(d_i-A\exp(-\alpha t_i))^2$.

To obtain the posterior probability, they integrate with respect to the variable A

$P(\alpha|D\rho I)\propto\int dA exp(-\frac{Q}{2\rho^2})$

> The integral over A is a Gaussian integral. It is evaluated by completing the square in Q, followed by a
> change of variables to transform the integral into a
> Gaussian.

to obtain

$P(\alpha|D\rho I) \propto exp(\dfrac{\bar{h}^2}{2\rho^2})$,

where

$\bar{h}^2= \dfrac{\{\sum_{i=1}^{N}(d_i\exp(-\alpha t_i))\}^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} \exp(-2\alpha t_i)}$.

I am assuming they use Laplace's method to evaluate the integral, but I don't understand how to complete the squares in $Q$ and what would be a good change of variables to obtain a Gaussian integral.

For inclined people interested in more details, see [paper, Appendix A1](https://bayes.wustl.edu/glb/HowAccurately.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write
$$Q=\sum_{i=1}^n (d_i- A \,a_i)^2 \qquad \text{with} \qquad a_i=e^{-\alpha t_i}$$

$$Q=A^2 \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2-2A\sum_{i=1}^n a_id_i+\sum_{i=1}^n d_i^2=A^2 S_1-2A S_2+S_3$$
$$A^2 S_1-2A S_2+S_3=S_1\left(A^2-2 \frac{S_2}{S_1}A+\left(\frac{S_2}{S_1}\right)^2\right)-S_1\left(\frac{S_2}{S_1}\right)^2+S_3$$
$$A^2 S_1-2A S_2+S_3=S_1\left(A-\frac{S_2}{S_1}\right)^2+\frac{S_1 S_3-S_2^2}{S_1}$$

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Claude!